# Error when binding repeater with IDataReader after converting asp.net 3.5 to 4.0

Tags: asp.net, idatareader

I am trying to migrate asp.net 3.5 application to asp.net 4.0 version.

asp.net 3.5 is working without any issues, after migrating to asp.net 4.0 getting the below error

> "An invalid data source is being used for rptStudents. A valid data
>   source must implement either IListSource or IEnumerable."

Note: Migrated to Enterprise library 5.0 from 4.1

Code:

```
Using drStudents As IDataReader = dbStudents.ExecuteReader(cmdStudents)
                With rptStudents
                    .DataSource = drStudents
                    .DataBind()
                End With
```

### End Using

Davide:Thanks for your quick response.

drStudents is a IDataReader and this code is working good

Dim dbStudents As Database = DatabaseFactory.CreateDatabase("eCONNECTION")
        Dim cmdStudents As DbCommand = dbComments.GetStoredProcCommand("get_students")

Using drStudents As IDataReader = dbStudents.ExecuteReader(cmdStudents)
                With rptStudents
                    .DataSource = drStudents
                    .DataBind()
                End With
            End Using

Answer (score 0):

What is the actual object type of the `drStudents` variable?

It is very clear from the error that `IDataReader` or the object you receive is not good anymore as `DataSource` and you should pass something that implements `IListSource` or `IEnumerable`

Comment: Davide:Thanks for your quick response. 
drStudents is a IDataReader and this code is working in aps.net 3.5 with enterprise library 4.1, getting an error when i migrate the application to asp.net 4.0 with enterprise library 5.0. 
Dim dbStudents As Database = DatabaseFactory.CreateDatabase("eCONNECTION") 
Dim cmdStudents As DbCommand = dbComments.GetStoredProcCommand("get_students") 
Using drStudents As IDataReader = dbStudents.ExecuteReader(cmdStudents) 
With rptStudents 
.DataSource = drStudents 
.DataBind() 
End With